# How to avoid using stack method from library in Java

Tags: java, stack

How do I code or make a stack from scratch without using stack method from the utility library?

Comment: please specify the library name, the class and the method you refer to.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you wonder how you could implement a stack from scratch. There are already examples of this on this site. However, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure-introduction-program/ provides a Java implementation how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should to create your own class, extend it from Vector, and implement all methods you need. Or just create your own class with all methods. Or you can extend your class from Stack class and override methods which behaviour you want to change

Answer (score 0):

A stack has a top item and a pointer to the rest of the stack. You can use a list or array for implementation

Stack is a linear data structure which follows a particular order in which the operations are performed.
Mainly the following three basic operations are performed in the stack:

Push: Adds an item in the stack. If the stack is full, then it is said to be an Overflow condition.

Pop: Removes an item from the stack. The items are popped in the reversed order in which they are pushed.

Peek or Top: Returns top element of stack.

isEmpty: Returns true if stack is empty, else false.

```
class Stack 
{ 
    static final int MAX_ELEMENT = 100; 
    int top; 
    int a[] = new int[MAX_ELEMENT]; // Maximum size of Stack 

boolean isEmpty() 
{ 
    return (top < 0); 
} 
Stack() 
{ 
    top = -1; 
} 

boolean push(int x) 
{ 
    if (top >= (MAX_ELEMENT -1)) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Stack Overflow"); 
        return false; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        a[++top] = x; 
        System.out.println(x + " pushed into stack"); 
        return true; 
    } 
} 

int pop() 
{ 
    if (top < 0) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Stack Underflow"); 
        return 0; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        int x = a[top--]; 
        return x; 
    } 
}
```

}